# How to display potrait image in landscape mode in flutter

Tags: flutter

So, I have clicked image in landscape mode. but when I try to display in potrait mode image is stretching.

```
SizedBox(
                              height: 230.h,
                              width: double.infinity,
                              child: Image.file(
                                File(image!.path),
                                fit: BoxFit.fill,
                              ),
                            )
```

Comment: can you include sample code-snippet that will reproduce the same error

Answer (score 0):

use the fit property of the Image widget.
The fit property controls how the image is scaled to fit within the available space

```
Image(
  image: AssetImage(''),
  fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
)
```

Comment: I tried that as well but image was stretching

Comment: share your code part that refer the fill

Comment: I have updated my que. Plz look that

Answer (score 0):

It's that to easy you can use `OrientationBuilder` and rotate your images with out lose quality

You can use below code:

```
OrientationBuilder(
  builder: (context, orientation) => Stack(
    alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
    children: [
      Image.network('Your Url'),
      IconButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          if ("Condition") {
            await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
              DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
              DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
            ]);
          } else {
            await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
              DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
              DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
            ]);
          }
        },
        icon: const Icon(
          Icons.screen_rotation_alt,
          color: Colors.white,
        )
      )
    ],
  ),
)
```

good luck ;)